# What datatype to use to store user permissions

Tags: c#

We've developed code that basically returns data for a user's permissions on an entity.
For instance, an entity could be one of the following:

```
-Company
-Contact
-Project
-Issue etc...
```

We then can assign policies (and a person can get multiple policies) that allow a user to perform an action:

```
-Create
-Edit
-Delete
-Export
```

So basically one policy could say that user A has the right to create a company, but another policy which this same user has says that he does not have the right to create a company.  In this case we take the rights that allow before the rights that dont allow.  In this example, he/she would be allowed to create a company.

So basically you end up with data like so:

```
Policy1 Company Create Yes
Policy1 Company Edit Yes
Policy1 Company Delete No
Policy2 Company Create No
Policy2 Company Edit   Yes
Policy2 Company Delete No
```

I have a query which we use to return what is this user's permission based on the rules we discussed.

In this case running the query the result would be:

```
Company create yes
Company edit yes
Company delete no
```

Our app isn't just a bit yes / no for whether they can perform the action or not.  We have yes / no / owner only (for records that should only be edited / deleted by the owner only.  Our query is great and is returning the correct data.

My question is what data type should I use in C# to basically say:

Given an entity (company) given an action (create) what is the value.  Basically at the end of the day I want to build a matrix that looks like this:

```
           Create     Edit        Delete
Company      Yes     Owner Only    Yes
Contact      No      No            No
Project      Yes     Yes          Owner Only
```

The rows on the first column represent the entity, the columns after that represent the actions (create, edit, delete).  The combination of the 2 for instance index:
`[Company][Create] = Yes` would give you the right of the action based on the entity.

So what datatype fits this model where I can perform some index like: `[Contact][Edit]=No`.
We also have to session this object / come up with a way (maybe dynamically) to get the result based on an entity and action.

I thought session would be good so that we can check the rights once and only once until the user logs out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up with:

```
 public class EntityPermission
    {
        private readonly List<GetUserPermissionsResult> _userPermissionDataSet;
        private readonly Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> _permissions;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor to generate permissions for a user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ds">
        /// Dataset of type List GetUserPermissionsResult
        /// based on a stored procedure which brings back the 
        /// valid permissions of a user.
        /// The result is a matrix of size [Enitities] * [Actions]
        /// Where each entity action [index] is the value (right).
        /// In general terms, the entity e with action a has right r.
        /// </param>
        public EntityPermission(List<GetUserPermissionsResult> ds)
        {
            _userPermissionDataSet = ds;
            _permissions = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
            SetPermissions();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called from the constructor of EntityPermission.
        /// This method fills our matrix of size entity * action with 
        /// the valid rights.
        /// </summary>
        public void SetPermissions()
        {
            var dt = _userPermissionDataSet;
            for (int i = 1; i<=Enum.GetNames(typeof(Module)).Length; i++)
            {
                var actionDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                for (int j = 1; j<=Enum.GetNames(typeof(ActionEnum)).Length; j++)
                {
                    var value = (from a in dt where a.EntityID == i && a.ActionID == j select a.Answer).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (value != null)
                        actionDictionary.Add(j , (int) value);
                    else actionDictionary.Add(j, (int)Answer.No);
                }
                _permissions.Add(i, actionDictionary);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to get the rights provided an entity (a module)
        /// and an action on that module.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityIdKey"></param>
        /// <param name="actionIdKey"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetPermission(int entityIdKey, int actionIdKey)
        {
            return _permissions[entityIdKey][actionIdKey]; 
        }   
    }
```

The readonly `List<GetUserPermissionsResult>` was a returned type from a sproc that returned a matrix based on my question - without too many details:

```
SELECT 
    e.EntityID AS EntityID,
    a.ActionID AS ActionID, 
    CASE MAX(ar.[Rank]) 
        WHEN 3 THEN 1   --yes
        WHEN 2 THEN 3   --originator only
        WHEN 1 THEN 2   --no
    END AS [Answer]
FROM
 ....
```

This sproc had a bunch of joins but basically grouped by the following:

```
GROUP BY
    e.EntityID,
    a.ActionID
```

This ensures we get an action per a module (the entity).

We stored this object as part of the user's session:

`public EntityPermission Permission { get; set; }`

And then we simply could make a call to GetPermission to get the result:

```
 if (((int)Answer.Yes ==
                 MySession.Current.Permission.GetPermission((int)Module.SubProject, (int)ActionEnum.Edit))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a final answer, but I thought about this and maybe I can get some feedback.  Here is what I came up with:

I was thinking about how to store the permissions and I believe I have come up with something that just might work.

I kept thinking throughout all of this is – all I need is a 2d matrix…then the obvious hit me, why simply do we not use a simple 2d int matrix?  It works, at least on paper it does.
As you know we have some enums:

```
Modules          Answer                 Action 
Contact = 1      Yes = 1                Create = 1
Corp = 2         No = 2                 Edit = 2
Company = 3      Originator Only = 3    Delete = 3
Program = 4                             View = 4
Project = 5                             List =5
SubProject  = 6                         Export = 6
Issue = 7       
LL = 8      
User = 9
```

In this case we have 9 modules with 6 action types, therefore we need a matrix of the size [9x6] to generate 54 possible entries based on the matrix[i,j].  This would work even if we added more modules and more actions.

The type is simply:
`int[,] permissions = new int[Enum.GetNames(typeof(Modules)).Length, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Action)).Length];`

Translates simply to: 
`int[,] permissions = new int[9,6]`

So far this gives us the matrix as an empty matrix.  We have to remember that arrays /  matrices in C# are zero based…which is fine.  We already have a stored procedure that returns the data like so:

```
Module       Action          Answer
1 (Contact)   1 (Create)     1 (Yes)
1 (Contact)   2 (Edit)       1 (Yes)
1 (Contact)   3 (Delete)     2 (No)
…..     
2 (Corp)      1 (Create)     1 (Yes)
2 (Corp)      2 (Edit)       1 (Yes)
Etc…etc…
```

So now to fill the array we have the following, this is just C# pseudo code:

```
for(int i=0; i<Enum.GetNames(typeof(Modules)).Length; i++) {
  Reader.read();  //read the first row from the database
   For(int j=0; j<Enum.GetNames(typeof(Action)).Length; j++) {
         Permissions[i,j] = reader[“Answer”];  //assign the answer from the returned row to the array
        If( j<Enum.GetNames(typeof(Action)).Length-1) {
            Reader.read(); //read next row in database
        } //end if condition
  } //end for j
} //end for i
```

This loop will simply produce the result of this:

```
             1 Create    2 Edit 3 Delete    4 View  5 List  6 Export
1(Contact)     1           1      2            1    1         1
2(Corp)        1           3      2            1    1         1
3(Company)     1           1      1            1    1         1
4(Program)     1           1      1            1    1         1
5(Project)     1           1      2            1    1         1
6(SubProject)  1           1      2            1    1         1
7(Issues)      1           1      1            2    1         1
8(LL)          1           1      1            1    1         1
9(User)        2           2      2            1    2         2
```

This would be per user…And this is exactly what I want because I want to write code similiar to this (remember this is just pseduo):

```
If(MySession.Current.Permission[(int)Module.Contact – 1, (int)Action.Create] == (int)Answer.Yes)
 {
  //this allows contact create
}
```

This is very flexible as we could potentially add any new modules without affecting anything.  I can reference things simply by `Permission[Module.ModuleIWant – 1, Action.ActionIWant – 1]`.

We simply ensure we take 1 away from it since the array is zero based…We don’t need anything else.  It's probably not the best solution but I think it can work...